# Error: app:mergeDebugResources FAILED, how to fix this?

Tags: android-studio

What could be the solution for this error?

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\ll\AndroidStudioProjects\Intro\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4e447e15.). Check logs for more details.

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project as well as locating the possible error. I found out that in my values.xml, , these are highlighted red. What could be the solution of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Find and exchange all ' symbols in your strings.xml or somewhere else in your code with \'